# Memory leak how to find and delocate

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am running a memory leak counter on my project and it says 2 of my 4 allocations are leaking. I think i have found them but am not sure, and dont even know how to delocate them. Two are members, m_color and m_data and two are parameters to those members, one in m_color and one in m_data.

```
class Screen {
public:
    Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
        : m_width(width), m_height(height),
          m_size(width*height), m_color(new TerminalColor[m_size]), <-?
          m_data(new char[m_size]) <-?
    {}
    ~Screen(){}
    void clear();
    void fill(char ch, const TerminalColor &color);
    void fillRect(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, char ch, const TerminalColor &color);
    void set(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, char ch, const TerminalColor &color);
    void setText(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, const std::string& text,  const TerminalColor &color);
    void setTextRect(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, const std::string& text,  const TerminalColor &color);
    void draw(Terminal &terminal);
private:
    const uint16_t m_width;
    const uint16_t m_height;
    const uint32_t m_size;
    TerminalColor *m_color; <-?
    char *m_data; <-?
};
```

Is it the members who are leaking, since i can not delocate them after i put in parameters? How to delocate them if so?

Comment: Your destructor is not freeing memory that your constructor allocates. Also, your class does not follow the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which could also cause leaks and other problems. And what does your `set()` method do? Does it reallocate the 2 members in question?

Comment: You seem to be using `new` without a corresponding `delete`. This is a 100% memory leak

Comment: @RemyLebeau so i should have delete m_data; in the destructor or simply ~m_data in the public section?

Comment: @Fureeish when new is in the header file, where do i use delete? in the destructor? Do i delete the parameters or the member?

Comment: The constructor of `Screen` dynamically allocates memory using `new[]`. That means, every time you create a `Screen` object, something is being `new[]`ed. What should then happen is every time a `Screen` is destroyed (e.g. while leaving a scope), it should *deallocate all memory the it dynamically allocated* with a `delete[]`. To achieve that, you should `delete[]` the `new[]`ed stuff by constructor *in the destructor*. In your case, `~Screen(){ delete[] m_data; delete[] m_color; }` should do it

Comment: @Fureeish yes it worked with delete[] instead of only delete. So the important thing is to look if the parameter is an array or not, regardless of what the member is from the beginning? Thank you

Comment: Yes. `new` should be accompanied by `delete` and `new[]` should be accompanied by `delete[]`. It is *undefined behaviour* to `delete` a `new[]`ed object and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the leak is that the constructor of `Screen` is dynamically allocating memory, using two `new` expressions, and there is no corresponding `delete` expression.

For this reason, a simple function like

```
 void f()
 {
      Screen x(some_width, some_height);
         // x is destructed as f() returns
 }
```

will cause a leak, since the memory allocated by `Screen`s constructor will never be released.

One solution is to add corresponding `delete` expressions to the destructor, such as  (within the class definition)

```
 ~Screen()
 {
     delete [] m_color;
     delete [] m_data;
 };
```

Be aware that the class may have other constructors - and some constructors are generated automatically by the compiler unless you prevent that (which you haven't).  It is necessary to ensure all constructors allocate memory in a similar manner to avoid undefined behaviour.  For example, a default-generated copy constructor will copy pointers rather than doing dynamic memory allocation.   Using it therefore results in two instances of `Screen` containing pointers to the same dynamically allocated memory.  When those objects are both subsequently destroyed, the shared  memory will be released twice.   The behaviour is then undefined.

A better option is to avoid using raw pointers, and use standard containers.   For example, give `m_color` the type `std::vector<TerminalColor>` and `m_data` the type `std::vector<char>`, and initialise them in constructor using something like

```
Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
    : m_width(width), m_height(height),
      m_size(width*height),
      m_color(m_size),      // initialise m_color to have m_size elements
      m_data(m_size)        // initialise m_data to have m_size elements
{}
```

The advantage of using standard containers is that you need not do anything in `Screen`s destructor, because the memory will be released automatically.   It also ensures other constructors play correctly (i.e avoids memory leaks) unless you go out of your way to change how those constructors behave

I've chosen to use `std::vector` as the standard container type.  Depending on needs, you may wish to use other container types.

One trade-off with using `std::vector` is that you MAY need to make minor adjustments of how elements of the arrays are accessed (e.g. if you need to pass a pointer to the first element of `m_color` to a function expecting an array, pass `&m_color[0]` rather than `m_color`) but those adjustments are simple.